# Why are SharePoint pdfs no longer opening from within the browser?

Tags: pdf, browser

I have upgraded a SharePoint, excatly same code, but now links to pdfs always prompt to save and dont open from within the browser (which they do on the old server)

old server is named: `localintranet`
new server is my local machine: `myserver:3200` (yes its on port 3200)

Any ideas?

I did try adding my server to the list of local intranet machines in internet explorer to no avail.

I have tried both `href=file.pdf target=_blank` and `onclick=window.open('file.pdf');return false;` in the anchor tag

driving me nuts!

Comment: Have you tried comparing HTTP headers between the requests on the old and the new machine? If not, please do, there's a 99% chance that the answer lies there. If you don't know how to do that, I recommend using the [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Comment: I didn't get that far, but you would be right (see my answer below). MS adding their own headers that only IE recognises. WTB more proprietary web please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta love microsoft

http://blog.brainlitter.com/archive/2010/05/19/sharepoint-2010-treats-pdf-and-other-file-types-as-insecure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
AddType application/pdf .pdf
```

line into your .htaccess file in the http root folder of your web server.

Comment: Are you sure he's using Apache webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. to be sure check:
   Adobe Reader.
   Choose Edit > Preferences.
   Select Internet in the list on the left.
   Display PDF in Browser should be OK.
2. probably server sends header for .pdf to download it, instead open inline?

   Header set Content-Disposition inline